# piggy backing multiple questions onto one with bounty

Tags: discussion, bounty

So, this question was asked on September 19, then a few days later it was edited to piggy-back another question into it, and a +50 bounty was opened on it.  The bounty ends in a few hours.

<sup>(It is a low quality question to begin with, it just lists some random superstitions, asking us to say it ain't so.)</sup>

I answered it, but then I thought that this is probably not a good idea, so I tried to close it as "too broad", but I was greeted by the following  message:

> This question has an open bounty and cannot be closed. [X]

Why should an open bounty on a question trump any other considerations of quality?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39568017/3001761), presumably - the use of formatting alone is troubling!